# webservice for autosuggest on city names / postal codes including long-lat coordinates?

Tags: web-services, autocomplete, geolocation

i'm looking for a webservice, to be used for an autocomplete field,
where people can fill in **either a postal code / city name or both**

this service will need **all cities in Europe**, so we can use it for all country websites.
and in a later stadium we want to keep the world open for asia and america so this would be a plus.

**preferably it would also return the long-lat coordinates for the locations,**

Now it is a free textfield, after leaving the field, we hit the google geocoding service, 
to find coordinates... preferably i would tie these two together.
so we don't have to query 2 services for one thing.

does anyone know of the existance of such a service online somewhere?
or would you suggest to build our own database with cities / postal codes / coordinates?
if so we would need to get the content from somewhere too, and i was trying to avoid that issue :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently searched for a similar service, in vain.

I wanted my users to have auto-complete on entering a city name, and once a city is chosen I needed to pass the name and lat/long onto the Google API. In the end I did this: -

1. downloaded the geonames allcountries.zip, full extract: [this](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/)
2. Imported it into a SQL DB via SSIS (about 7.5 million records!)
3. Wrote a simple query to extract just the cities (only the PPLC, PPLA and PPLA2 records).

This left me with a manageable table of 9112 records (with lat / long and country code) which covers all the cities in the world. I then wrote my own code to query the data.

Not ideal, but I needed a solution.

Comment: on top of that i would need to manage the translations too
but i find it odd you would have all cities in the world fit into 9k records, there have to be more than 9k cities in the whole world no?

Comment: Who knows? I don't think there is a definitive answer to that. With the GeoNames data though, you can decide what you want to consider a city. I chose to use their PPLA/A2 codes and that seems to include any city I can think of - but you could base it on population numbers instead or include lower level PPL codes (e.g. towns, villages). have a look at this list: http://www.geonames.org/export/codes.html - perhaps there's no webservice because it's so bloody difficult to decide what the list of cities are!

Comment: i think i'm going to build me a manual solution like you did then :)
thanks for the tips

Comment: @Sander You may not need to. I looked further and geonames do have a city lookup web service - take a look at this demo:  http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is very old but for thouse who are looking for a simple solution that can be integrated in 5 minutes here is the link: 
[Geocomplete jQuery...](https://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/)

For my case I followed this steps:

1 - Download the plugin from [here](https://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/).

2 - Add the jquery.geocomplete.js or jquery.geocomplete.min.js file into your javascript folder of your project.

3 - Call this file in script tags on the html page where you have the input field that you have to autocomplete with cities: 
`<script src='/PathToTheFile/jquery.geocomplete.js'></script>`

4 - To convert an input into an autocomplete field, simply call the Geocomplete plugin in script tags: `<script>
   $("#IdOfTheInputField").geocomplete();  // Option 1: Call on element.
   $.fn.geocomplete("input"); // Option 2: Pass element as argument.
 </script>`

5- You can check for the complete list of options on the link provided at the top.

Hope that this helped!

Comment: i appreciate your sharing but it always better to write good qaulity answers [Good Answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)