# google suggested city name autocomplete

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to build a web page in which I want to use google suggested city/state name combinations when user starts typing their address, it auto completes the city and state just like in google maps.

For reference visit this URL:

[Google Maps](http://maps.google.co.in/maps?hl=en&q=wre&gs_upl=3228l3481l0l4313l3l3l0l0l0l0l412l812l4-2l2l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&biw=1366&bih=667&um=1&ie=UTF-8&ei=okaATqeFDdHKrAfLspkB&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=3&ved=0CBcQ_AUoAg)

When someone start typing in top left green A box. it gives you auto suggested list.

Can any one help me do the same thing for my web site? Or is there such google api exist that I can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Job for the Places AutoComplete API :-)

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete.html

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Google Maps JavaScript API V3 did the trick for me. I got the answer before your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason it has to be google suggested names?

Here's an api that provides autocomplete for city names plus a lot of extra data you can squeeze out about the city (population, life quality data, even photo)

http://developers.teleport.org/api/

more specifically the widget http://developers.teleport.org/api/autocomplete_widget/

Answer (score 0):

google does not provide such a service for autosugest,
google does have a service for getting the geocodes and more, when you have the full address.

take a look in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254982/webservice-for-autosuggest-on-city-names-postal-codes-including-long-lat-coordi), where i had the same issue, i'm looking for a service that gives me the city names and addresses

there was a suggestion from someone to use geonames.com as a service, but i'm not sure they have streetnames as well...